# Porque os.chdir() no funciona

Tags: python

tengo un código que utiliza paths y no cambia el directorio actual
al utilizar cd debería cambiar de directorio usando chdir() pero esto no ocurre.

```
import os

Path = os.getcwd()

while True:
    Command = input(f"{Path} - >")
    if Command == "quit":
        quit()
    elif "cd" in Command:
        if len(Command) >= 5:
            CDCommand = Command.split(' ')
            os.chdir(CDCommand[1])
            print(Path)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error está en que nunca actualizas el valor de `Path`, por lo que pareciera estar siempre en el mismo directorio.

Esta es la versión corregida:

```
while True:
    Path = os.getcwd()
    Command = input(f"{Path} - >")
    if Command == "quit":
        quit()
    elif "cd" in Command:
        if len(Command) >= 5:
            CDCommand = Command.split(' ')
            os.chdir(CDCommand[1])
```

produce:

```
/home/candid/.config/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2021.2/scratches - >/home/candid
/home/candid/.config/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2021.2/scratches - >cd /home/candid
/home/candid - >cd /home/candid/inter
/home/candid/inter - >quit

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Vaya error mas tonto que he provocado (siempre que uso ciclos while  me pasa algo parecido)